# Format Range of Numbers in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, range, number-formatting

I am a professor using Google Sheets and [a pasted code](http://pastebin.com/gyRK9B19) in Script Editor to create a gradebook in which individual students can view only their grades. (For development of that code see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993834/google-apps-script-display-single-column-based-on-user-email/15998092#15998092).) I am having some trouble formatting numbers, however, as I need different formats for specific ranges from the spreadsheet. The current code formats numbers using:

```
if (typeof(value)=='number'){return Utilities.formatString('%.2f',value)}
```

This is within a longer`function string(value)`that also formats "string" and "objects."

I'm wondering if there's a way to customize that command so I can have percentages for a specific range and decimals for another? Or would I need to use a different function? (This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616254/formatting-numbers-within-google-apps-script-javascript-code) offers some options, but amateur that I am, I haven't figured out how to get any of the suggestions to work within the current code. I may simply need advice on where to paste an existing piece of code.)

Comment: Do you need your code to determine what named range the values are coming from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sandy. If possible, yes. I have a chunk of cells that contain "overall grades" that I'd like to show up as percentages and a different chunk of cells that should show up just as numbers.

Comment: Learning how to troubleshoot will be one of the best investments of your time.  [Google Documentation - troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)  If you have a specific line of code that gives an error, or an unexpected result, it's easier for someone to help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like the code that you are using is deprecated. The [UiApp class (line 37. of your code) is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app). If I have more time, I could help you develop a new system, but for now it should work.

I would suggest formatting the output of the range en masse. I am assuming that for each gradebook entry, there is a specific range of information. Instead of formatting each cell based on the return values of `string(value)`, I would use the [`setNumberFormats(object)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object)) method that is a part of [SpreadSheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll be honest - I'm a complete amateur here just sort of mucking around in javascript and hoping it will work. I'll see what I can figure out with the setNumberFormats(object). Any additional help/advice you have time to offer would be most appreciated, but I realize everyone's busy. :)